# HTTP requests between React app to express inside Docker containers

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I am trying to send an HTTP request with Axios from react that build into Nginx container to express that build into node container.
when I am using the container name for the HTTP request to communicate between different backend containers everything works,
but when I try it with react app it fails and sends me a CORS error. this only works if I explicitly type the express container IP address.
I am using docker-compose to build everything so I don't know the address before.
there is a way to get around this issue?

```
  cinema-svc:
    build: ../cinema_web-service/cinema-svc
    container_name: cinema-svc
    depends_on:
      - auth-svc
      - subs-svc
      - users-svc
    networks:
      - cinemanet
      - frontnet
    restart: unless-stopped
  

  react-client:
    build: ../react_client/client
    container_name: react-client
    depends_on:
      - cinema-svc
    networks:
      - frontnet
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

**Update**

this is what solved my issue:

```
 cinema-svc:
    build: ../cinema_web-service/cinema-svc
    container_name: cinema-svc
    depends_on:
      - auth-svc
      - subs-svc
      - users-svc
    networks:
      cinemanet:  
      frontnet:
        ipv4_address: '172.25.0.20'
    restart: unless-stopped
  

  react-client:
    build: ../react_client/client
    container_name: react-client
    depends_on:
      - cinema-svc
    networks:
      - frontnet
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: unless-stopped

  
networks:
  frontnet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.25.0.0/24
```

Comment: The `ipv4_address:` you specify is unreachable, unless your browser is physically on the same host and it's a native-Linux host.

Comment: David Maze, thank you i will fix it, you have any suggestions? networking are not my strong part

Comment: You need to connect to the published `ports:` of the backend service, or better, run both halves behind a reverse proxy and use a URL-only path like `/api` to reach the backend.

Comment: Oh I understand I'm exposing the port on the Dockerfile itself. and make a request from react to the backend like that http://172.25.0.20:3100 for example. and  i will read about reverse proxy thank you